# I am looking for IHttpClientFactory -> HttpMethod.Post example

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I want to use `IHttpClientFactory` for consuming my API.

There are so many examples on how you can use `SendAsync` to request data from the API but what if I want to post data using `IHttpClientFactory`?

I tried something like this but then where do I pass the object?

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://localhost:44357/api/users/validateuser");

var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a POST, it passes a serialized object to the API and receives back JSON for deserialization:

```
var result;

try
{
    HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyAPI");
    //2 minute timeout on wait for response
    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
    //Create an HttpRequestMessage object and pass it into SendAsync()
    HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage();
    message.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    message.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    message.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
    message.RequestUri = new Uri(client.BaseAddress.ToString() + "someapiendpoint");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);
    result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //deserialize the result into proper object type
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Log exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://localhost:44357/api/users/validateuser");

request.Content = foo; //is where you pass the payload
```

`Content` is the type of `HttpContent` which is an abstract class you cannot instantiate it, but you have multiple classes inheriting from it:

`ByteArrayContent`, `MultipartContent`, `ReadOnlyMemoryContent`, `StreamContent`, `FormUrlEncodedContent`, `MultipartFormDataContent` and `StringContent`. The most common is `StringContent` so you can serialize your C# object into a JSON string using any kind of JSON serializer (`Newtonsoft`, `System.Text.Json` serializer, etc).
Example with `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;


var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);
request.Content = new StringContent(jsonContent);
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may actually answer the user's question, it would be better to include an explanation with it so that other users can understand what this means in the context of the original question.

Comment: @Christine thanks for your sensible comment! Added better description to my answer

Comment: Great breakdown in your explanation.